# How to iteratively fit a brms regression model and extract means and sigma to the dataframe

Tags: r, function, data.table, tidyr, rstan

Given the sample data `sampleDT` below, I would appreciate any help to iteratively fit the brms model below n times, and each time extract the `means` and `sigma` from the brmsfit object `brm.fit.n` and add them to the data frame `sampleDT`.

If `n=10`, then there should be 10 columns of `means` and 10 columns of `sigma` added to the data frame.

My attempt below does not work as intended. It allows me to run the brms model `n` times and generate the `means` and `sigma` `n` times, but does not add them to the data frame - one column for each means and one column for each sigma from each run - as intended.

**#sample data**

```
sampleDT<-structure(list(id = 1:10, N = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), A = c(62L, 96L, 17L, 41L, 212L, 143L, 143L, 
    143L, 73L, 73L), B = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 170L, 21L, 0L, 33L, 62L, 
    17L), C = c(0.05, 0.01, 0, 0.05, 0.8, 0.15, 0, 0.23, 0.85, 0.23
    ), employer = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), G = c(1.94, 1.19, 1.16, 
    1.16, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), H = c(0.14, 0.24, 
    0.28, 0.28, 0.21, 0.12, 0.17, 0.07, 0.14, 0.12), dollar.wage_1 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_2 = c(1.93, 
    1.18, 3.15, 3.15, 1.12, 1.12, 2.12, 1.12, 1.11, 1.11), dollar.wage_3 = c(1.95, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13), dollar.wage_4 = c(1.94, 
    1.18, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_5 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_6 = c(1.94, 
    1.18, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_7 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_8 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_9 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_10 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**#my attempt**

```
map_dfc(1:10, function(i) {
        brm.fit.n <-brm(dollar.wage_1 ~ A + B + C + employer + F + G + H,
                data=sampleDT, iter = 200, family = gaussian())
        sampleDT$mean.n<-fitted(brm.fit.n)[, 1]
        sampleDT$sd.n<-summary(brm.fit.n)$spec_pars[1]
        return(sampleDT)
    })
```

This question has also been posted [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/how-to-iteratively-fit-a-brms-regression-model-and-extract-means-and-sigma-to-the-dataframe/7690). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It looks like you have a pretty good idea what you want to do, have you tried writing the function yourself? What are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: Thanks, @Marius. Just edited the question to add my attempt so far - which does not produce the output in the desired structure. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things you need to do to adapt your existing code into a function are:

- Repeat the fit `n` times
- Save the output in a nice structure

There are lots of ways to do both parts, one option is `purrr::map_dfr` which can do both, applying the fit multiple times and creating a dataframe.

Instead of a `brm` model, which takes some time to fit, I've fit a simple linear model to random data instead, you would just have to replace those parts with your fitting code and save the mean and sd instead of the intercept and slope:

```
library(purrr)

# 1:10 - will repeat 10 times
map_dfr(1:10, function(i) {
    random_data = data.frame(
        x = rnorm(30),
        y = rnorm(30)
    )
    fit = lm(y ~ x, data = random_data)
    intercept = coef(fit)[1]
    slope = coef(fit)[2]
    return(data.frame(intercept, slope))
}, .id = "sim_num")
```

Which gives a dataframe as output:

```
   sim_num    intercept       slope
1        1  0.274903632 -0.03529736
2        2 -0.005134599 -0.22063748
3        3 -0.134999713  0.12090366
4        4 -0.216886033  0.21265679
5        5  0.261365432  0.02434036
6        6  0.067069791  0.23180334
7        7 -0.235138217  0.28360061
8        8 -0.117489553  0.10781101
9        9 -0.150288480  0.03086797
10      10 -0.031814194 -0.04075479
```